# Writing custom Insert/Update command for OleDbDataAdapter

Tags: c#, sql, dataset, oledb, insert-update

I am using OleDbDataAdapter to fill a table in the DataSet. The problem is that select sql statement is very complex (using left joins to get data from numerous tables) and OleDbCommandBuilder can't write an insert/update statement for me.

I was wondering what is the best course of action here? There aren't that many columns in which data could change (only 6-8 out of 30 or so needed) however it is important that I can do the OleDbDataAdapter.Update as simply as possible (speed and resource usage is very important).

Does anyone have any experience doing this? What is the best/recommended course of action here?

Thank you for your input!

EDIT: I could also use some help with writing update statements for OleDbDataAdapter, especialy when it involves multi-table update's. If anyone can point me to some literature, that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you hand-code the SQL in this case.